# Visual Studio Code shortcuts for jupyter

Tags: jupyter, visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm trying to make keybindings for some jupyter commands in VSC with the Python extension.
Say, I want to bind `runallcellsabove` command to `ctrl+alt+cmd+d`. 
Added the folowing code to keybindings.json (just copied from the sibling `runcurrentcell` command and changed "key" and "command" fields) :

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+cmd+d",
        "command": "python.datascience.runallcellsabove.palette",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && python.datascience.featureenabled && python.datascience.hascodecells && !editorHasSelection"
    }
```

Now, I can see this shortcut in `Keyboard Shortcuts`:
[image]

But nothing seems to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed since this was asked, but as of 2021:

> Sorry but most of the custom editor settings do not apply yet to the Jupyter notebook editors.
>
> They aren't being hosted inside of VS code, but inside of a separate process that uses an editor that looks a lot like VS code's. We need to port all of the functionality for VS code over to this new editor before it will work there as well.
>
> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1447#issuecomment-542282705

I believe these are embedded code-mirror editors - there are code-mirror config suggestions in here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1447 which you might adapt to implement your own keybindings.

Meanwhile - seems native keys will arrive soon?

[Native Notebooks - Essential Jupyter Shortcuts to be supported · Issue #4376 · microsoft/vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4376)